# AngularJS load array of elements partially by scrolling down

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have an application with adverbs, which is displayed to user.
There could be a hundreds of advertizing panels, and I would like to load them to user partially when it scrolls down. Almost like it works on the Facebook's wall.

Application is written in Angular and styled by Bootstrap.
The advertizing panel wrapped in divs:

```
<div class="row">
    <div ng-repeat="ad in ads">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-body fixed-panel">
                    <a href=""><img src="{{ ad.Logo}}"</a>
                    <h4 class="editContent text-center text-primary">{{ ad.Name }}</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: you need an infinite scroll plugin... take a look at [this](https://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/)

Comment: Thanks, really useful script.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle it using jQuery

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {
        // get ads and append(push) them to $scope.ads
    }
 });
```